# filtering a signal

Tags: capacitor, resistors, filter, power-electronics

I have two signal yellow and green which i'm doing an xor operation with both and now i get blue signal as an output but the problem is it has a spikes as you can see in every half period. could someone help me in removing that or any ideas?

thank you

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yellow and green input waveforms are changing at the same instant in time and this presents an EXOR gate with a resolution problem - if green slightly changes before yellow then the EXOR output will change but this will be rapidly extinguished as yellow changes.

So either live with the anomaly or find another way of achieving your goal. You might be able to use a delay circuit and some logic to remove the fast pulses but this wholly depends on what you are trying to ultimately achieve.

Comment: yeah. does filtering works in here?

Comment: It might but also it might not. I cannot tell you what type of filter (or whether it will work) because you are not explaining what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i'm just playing with gates and i wanted to see if the online simulation and theoretical results matches with my hardware setup. And here BLUE signal is my final output

Comment: Well, the circuit appears to be behaving exactly as I would expect it to given that green and yellow change approximately at the same point in time. If the simulation gives different results then it's likely that the sim has green and yellow changing at the same identical point in time and, for a sim that uses a simplistic EXOR model, this might produce an output without the glitches (as you call them).

Comment: i would like to remove the transition spike (probably filtering)? But don't know how to go about it!

Comment: Filtering the blue signal can remove the spike but it will delay the signal. The time delay might be up to three times longer than the width of the spike. This might not be acceptable. Then, to restore the digital quality of the filtered blue signal a schmitt trigger might have to be added. Because you "appear" to want a blue signal that is 90 degrees shifted from the yellow signal, this might be a serious problem.

Comment: oh.Any idea through which i could achieve it?

Comment: I do not know what you are ultimately trying to achieve. This or that could be suggested but I'm not about to start guessing what might work without you stating what you are trying to ultimately achieve and why the glitches are so problematic. It's quite possible that a totally different approach might be better.

Comment: You are getting what you expect to get from a combinational gate where glitches can happen like this on transition edges.....Are you trying to change the behaviour of gates or what ? @kundraputarunkumar

Comment: yea, i need to remove the glitches as now period of the output signal has changed and so does the frequency. But i need a better blue signal without the glitch. do you have any idea?

Comment: A possible solution might be to invert the green signal and use a divide-by-2. I'm suggesting this because it looks like the yellow signal is derived by using a divide-by-2 on the uninverted green signal.

Answer (score 1):

Green and yellow outputs are clearly being generated by a divide by 4 counter, or the two LSBs of a divide by 2^N counter.

In a synchronous counter (like HC16x for instance), these outputs change at *nominally* the same time. However, there will be slight differences due to slight differences in propagation delay, current drive, loading etc between outputs. Either output might change first. It's usual for these differences to be less than a propagation delay, so I would expect an HC163 driving an HC86 not to produce these spikes, the reaction time of the 86 being too long to respond to the difference in arrival time of the two inputs. However they could occur for extreme differences in loading, and a system that relied on this would be asking for trouble.

In an asynchronous or ripple counter (like HC393), the outputs change sequentially, with a whole propagation delay between the fastest changing Q output, and the next divider that it is clocking. Eyeballing your scope trace, it appears that the yellow trace is significantly lagging the green one, suggesting that they are being produced by an asynchronous counter. The delay between inputs is enough to allow the 86 to respond.

The proper system solution to get glitch-free operation is to re-latch the output of the XOR (or any combinatorial logic that is driven by nominally simultaneous transitions) *once it has settled*. An appropriate clock for that would be a delayed version of the clock that's clocking your counter, or perhaps an inverted version of it.

A kludgy solution would be to put an RC filter after the XOR, or maybe just a small C to ground on its output, to filter out the spike.

Another solution would be to switch to a much slower family for the XOR (say switch from an HC86 to a CD4070), which is effectively increasing the duration of input changes required to make it respond.

If the signals are from a ripple counter, then switching to a synchronous counter may well eliminate the spikes, but may not, and this should not be relied on in a proper design.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer Neil. Would try them!

Comment: so what is generating your green and yellow waveforms?

Comment: i'm just using the signal generator to get green an yellow